# Diferencia entre DataSource y DriverManager

Tags: java, base-de-datos, aplicación-web, java-ee, tomcat

Como dice el título, quiero saber cual es la diferencia entre `DataSource` y `DriverManager` en una aplicación web utilizando Tomcat. Hasta el momento se que `DataSource` sirve como una pool de conexiones hacia una base de datos mientras que `DriverManager` solo me brinda una conexión cada vez que le pida. ***Si puede ser***, me vendría bien una respuesta profundizada en el tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) es la clase que permite cargar los [`Driver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html)s de base de datos y crear conexiones a una o más bases de datos. En Java SE, es la única clase que se conecta con los drivers cargados y obtiene una conexión a base de datos. Esto lo hace mediante el método `Driver#connect`.

[`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) es la interfaz que permite definir un pool de conexiones. Las implementaciones de esta interfaz, lo que harán, serán crear un grupo de conexiones y estarán almacenadas en un espacio en memoria (esto se conoce como pool). Para crear las conexiones, internamente hacen uso de `DriverManager#getConnection` múltiples veces (1 por conexión) o de `Driver#connect` y las configuraciones que se hayan cargado para crear la instancia de `DataSource`.